# Delete Excel Blank Columns permanently using Java

Tags: java, excel

My Excel Sheet look like this:

```
Column Index:  [0]         [1]       [2]     [3]
Column Name :  Name      Password          Address  
               XYZ         111              Delhi
               ABC         222              Chennai
```

Here column at index[2] whose cell type is BLANK.I want to delete the columns of CELL_TYPE_BLANK.

I could able to find columns and their index numbers which are CELL_TYPE_BLANK, but I don't find the method to delete those columns permanently from Excel sheet.How to code to meet my requirement?

My output Excel sheet should look like below after deleting CELL_TYPE_BLANK columns.

```
Column Index:  [0]         [1]       [2]
Column Name :  Name      Password  Address  
               XYZ         111      Delhi
               ABC         222     Chennai
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class DeleteColumn
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Delete_Columns.xls"));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Cell cell;
Column column;
Row row= sheet.getRow(0);
int numXolumns = row.getLastCellNum();

for(int col=0; col< numXolumns; col++)
{
       cell = row.getCell(col);

       int type = cell.getCellType();
       if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) 
       {
           System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "+ cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL"+ cell.toString());
           int Delete_column_index=cell.getColumnIndex();
       }

  }
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Output_Excel.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
}
}
```

The code I implemented to delete the rows is

```
public static void removeRow()
{
    try
    {
     int getLastCell=row.getLastCellNum()-1;
     int lastIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum();
     for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++)
     {
       row=sheet.getRow(i);
       if(row.getCell(getLastCell)!=null && ((row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not valid for this App Type".trim()))|| (row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Applicable".trim()))))
           {
        sheet.shiftRows(i+1, lastIndex, -1);
            i--;
         }
     }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How to delete the columns?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a column in one shot. You need to delete one cell on each row.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to code? I want to implement this functionality in my project.